# OAuth2 Яндекс на Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, oauth2

В [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/id/doc/dg/index.html) явно проблемы с последовательностью...

Во-общем,

1. Создал приложение в личном кабинете. Указал в поле "Callback URI"  - где буду ловить ответ (redirect_uri)
2. Скачал и поставил на сайт кнопку "Войти через Яндекс". На кнопку поставил ссылку:

   ```
   link_yandex_auth = f'https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={client_id}&' \
                 f'redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&login_hint={login_hint}&scope={scope}&'\
                 f'force_confirm=yes&display=popup'
   ```

   `login_hint` - указал email

   `scope` - указала права, указанные при создании приложения
3. Пытаюсь поймать токен на странице **redirect_uri**, но он приходит в адресной строке после знака #, соответственно через **request.values.get()** он не достается (если бы был не **#** а **?**, то достал бы)

- Соответственно взяв из документации js-скрипт:

```
var token = /access_token=([^&]+)/.exec(document.location.hash)[1];
```

Он достается, но лежит теперь уже на странице и соответственно в роутах Flask к нему нет доступа, а как мне его закидывать в заголовок и отправлять на

> https://login.yandex.ru/info?format=json&with_openid_identity=yes

чтобы взять email пользователя?

Может, что-то я не так делаю?

Comment: Столкнулся с похожей проблемой, символ # всё портит. Но я начинаю сомневаться что # сделана случайно. Видимо после того, как js взял token необходимо создать аякс запрос к серверу (бэкэнду), передав токен. А уже на сервере долбиться на login.yandex. Буду очень благодарен вам, Алексей, если вы подтвердите мои соображения.

Comment: @Zlatov, На сколько я помню, там 2 запроса надо делать 1ый чтобы получить токен, 2-ой чтобы взять данные, которые разрешил пользователь брать

Answer (score 0):

Да, всё верно, нужно делать два запроса. Из документации это не сразу видно, так как нет сжатого описания "как это работает", а сразу длинные портянки подробного описания.

Правда мои шаги относятся не к Flask а к RubyOnRails, но кажется суть в том-же...

**Первый шаг** - Достигается подключением скрипта **sdk-suggest.js** на странице где показываем кнопку яндекса (или виджет). Происходит вызов пользователем страницы [https://Redirect.URI/для/веб/сервисов#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&expires_in=123456789](https://Redirect.URI/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&token_type=bearer&expires_in=123456789)

**Второй шаг** - Достигается подключением скрипта **sdk-suggest-token.js** на странице [https://Redirect.URI/для/веб/сервисов#..](https://Redirect.URI/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2#..). Этот скрипт, если я правильно понял, должен отработать и отправить запрос на наш бэк и сразу закрыть это всплывающее окно.

Comment: Если это у Вас работает, то могу посчитать правильным ответом) Я просто помню, что такое реализовал чисто беком без фронта, т.к. посчитал это безопаснее(потому как токен светить особо не хотелось на фронте)